# Regular expression show results if expression doesn't match

Tags: regex

Seemingly simple task. I need to display a line if a match is not found. Or, said another way, I need to not display a line if a match is found. I suspect this involves a look ahead assertion of some kind but can't figure out how.

I've tried finding a match and then trying to negate it with ^. But that doesn't seem to work. Also tried finding a match and putting {0} next to it: (wordhere){0}

Comment: Don't display a line if a match is found

Comment: What language are you using? Can't you just use your languages logical negation operator (Probably `!`) to invert the result of a match and then output your line?

Comment: Regular expression is not so good at just showing you lines that don't match.  In fact, I'm not even sure if there is a good way to find out what line number you are even on.  You might have to split the file by \r\n into an array, then run the regex on each line, and if it matches, skip it.  If it doesn't match, add the line number to another array.  Then you'll have two arrays, one with the data, and one with the line numbers that didn't match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use a negative lookahead. E.g.

```
^(?!something$).*$
```

will match anything besides "something".

Note that it may however be much more appropriate and better to read if you do a positive match and use control structures like `if not ...` to define which line is printed and which line is not.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use grep,

```
grep -v <expr>
```

does what you want.